# Allow only one uiviewcontroller to rotate

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ios6, screen-rotation

I'm working on an app using IIViewDeck and I only want one view controller  to rotate. It's ios 6 and I was able to work out the shouldRotate cascading to get the one that I need to rotate successfully.

My problem is that if I'm in landscape then switch to another view controller, the app remains in landscape. I need to force it back to protestor but I haven't had any success. I thought the simplest approach would be to do some 'force portait' code in the rotatable view controller's viewWillDisapper but I just don't know how to enforce.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is also asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018308/ios-6-uiinterfaceportrait-only-viewcontroller-being-presented-stuck-in-landsca)

In all your VC's say yes to rotation, but use an NSUInterger to set the mode like so:

The answer that questions has is below:

```
 -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
  return YES;
}

//keep the below code in all your VC's that you do not want to have the rotation capability

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
  return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the response but that is not the answer. That will not explicity restore the portrait orientation once the orientation has be switched to landscape unless the user rotates the device. I'd like to switch the orientation back manually if I'm not in my view that needs to support landscape